# Set up logging 4 Google Cloud storage: Need your help people

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

Issue:
I am trying to set up storage & access logging in GOOGLE CLOUD PLATFORM for all objects within a specific bucket, and have the data stored in another bucket. These objects being logged are mp3 files, that will be downloaded by users of my music website. I need logging so I can keep track of how many downloads each mp3 file(object) is receiving in the form of counts.

```
 Bucket I need Logged: strmazimbabwe/dancehall/singles
 Bucket where logs will be stored: strmazimbabwe/dancehall/download-loggging
```

I have been using the google shell command line, and am getting the same error. ive attached images showing the structure of our folders and error message in the command line. how can i resolve this please.
[Command line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RKEo.png)
[object within folder i need logged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsIH2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you can't specify part of bucket for logging, just an entire bucket. `strmazimbabwe/dancehall/singles` is not a bucket, `strmazimbabwe` is the bucket. As you can't log a bucket to itself, create a new bucket, e.g. `strmazimbabwe_logs` and run:

```
gsutil logging set on -b gs://strmazimbabwe -o AccessLog gs://strmazimbabwe_logs
```

Comment: oh i get what you mean. so its not possible to log files residing in a sub folder/bucket. You can only log the entire bucket.

Comment: Mark the answer as answered if it was answered